# My calculus about mean and standard deviation doesn't work

Tags: c++

let's assume that I have the sum of the integer in my variable mean and the sum of the scarred integer in my variable std. I want to have the mean and the standard deviation with respectively 3 and 4 numbers after the decimals point. But I don't have the expected value at all for the mean and the std :

```
int main(){
mean = double(int((double(mean)/(n-1))*1000))/1000;
  std = double(int(sqrt(double(std)/(n-1) - mean*mean)*10000))/10000;
  return 0;
}
```

I put double(int(....*1000))/1000 to have the 3 numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that reproduces the problem? One that actually compiles? Right now we dont have the type of either variable and std uses... itself in the computation but we dont know how it was initialized

Comment: Always perform computations with full precision. Restricting precision for formatting should be done as part of the output step.

Comment: You might have a look at `std::setprecision`

Comment: I am supposed to get, for mean = 5.45 and std = 5.9433 at the begining, a mean = 1.090 and a std = 0.0265 and instead I get mean = 1.362 and std = 214748. I will check setprecision, thanks

Comment: What is your value of `n` ? I made a test with your programe and it seems to work

Comment: Excuse-me, n = 5

Comment: Thank you for allowing me to know setprecision, my code is cleaner than before. Anyway, I always get wrong result for mean, and I got an nan for std

Comment: For the mean, `5.45/4 = 1.3625` and `5.45/5 = 1.09`

Comment: Mistake is mine, I have to divide by n and not n-1.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't mix your rounding policy inside the calculation unless absolutely necessary (due to legislation with money for example). Compute your distribution moments then round afterwards. In this case you probably don't want to round the mean that you pass to the standard deviation calculation.

Comment: @JeanHenriDeSartres: You sure? One is the standard deviation, the other is the estimator for the standard deviation of the population.

Comment: It seems I got the good value about the mean and a better value for the std. Do you know if it is possible to make setprecision display the significant number of digits I want, even if I add 0's behind it ?

Comment: @JeanHenriDeSartres: I normally just roll with whatever the C++ runtime library decides to output to the console. If you want arbitrary leading and trailing zeros then it's time to use `std::string` methinks.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue was to correct the formulas:
you need to divide by `n` for the `mean`, and by `n-1` for the variance.

To get exactly the expected number of figures after the decimal point, it is better to
perform the calculations with best possible precision, and then for the final display to combine

```
<< std::fixed << set precision (3) << ...
```

With this solution, you get some additional zeros at the end if necessary.

Output:

```
mean = 1.090
std deviation = 0.0265
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    double sum_x = 5.45;
    double sum_x2 = 5.9433;
    int n = 5;
    
    double mean = sum_x/n;
    double variance = sum_x2/n - mean*mean;
    variance *= double (n)/(n-1);       // correction to get an unbiased estimation
    double std_deviation = std::sqrt (variance);
    
    std::cout << "mean = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << mean << "\n";
    std::cout << "std deviation = " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << std_deviation << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd shy away from using `std` as a variable name in C++. Also `mean = mean/n;` is an abuse. It's very important to be precise when writing quantitative code.

Comment: @Bathsheba I simply tried to follow OP's notation to introduce as less modifications as possible. OK, code modified.

Comment: One slight indulgence on my part, then an upvote!